# How to loop through folders and rename files? *_abc.txt to *_abc_xyz.txt? how to use for loop?

Tags: windows, command-line

```
for /r %%G in (*_abc.txt) do ren "%%~G" *_abc_xyz.txt
```

I keep getting this error: %%G was unexpected at this time.

Comment: what scripting language?

Comment: Looks to be windows .bat file

Comment: yes, for batch file to run from command line - windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR variables use a single `%` when run from the command line, and double `%%` when within a batch script.

So to run on the command line, you need:

```
for /r %G in (*_abc.txt) do ren "%G" *_abc_xyz.txt
```